# Merging Excel cells does not work PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

need bit of help with PHPExcel.

I am saving data from MySQL table to Excel file.

It almost works, grabs data from database fine, and writes to excel file, but i want to merge 2 columns together, that does not work.

Here's my PHP code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['dir']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['sta']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['std']);
    $rowCount++;
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:C1');
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');
```

As you see after while loop i try to merge columnds B & C together, but it doesnt work.

Screenshot of output file:

[image]

I want it to be something like this:

[image]

I hope you guys understand what i mean and can tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: No, I don't understand what you mean.... you tell PHPExcel to mege cells `B1:C1`, and your actual output is showing cells `B1:C1` as merged.... it does exactly what you've told it to do

Comment: What I can't figure out is what you actually want it to do, but it certainly isn't merging cells.... I'm guessing you want to show either `$row['sta'])` or `$row['std'])` in cell `B1`, and nothing in cell `C1`.... maybe something like `if(empty($row['std'])) { $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['sta']); } else { $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['std']); }`

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, i want to move time data from cell C to cell B  so they are all in one column. Like last picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge cells does merge cells.. it does not evaluate there content.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Merge-and-unmerge-cells-f7850c71-8663-429a-9316-aa09fc161eaf

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['dir']);
    if (!empty($row['sta']) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['sta']);
    } else {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['std']);
    }
    $rowCount++;
}
//$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:C1');
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');
```

Comment: Just what I was about to suggest. A much simpler and more obvious solution based on how the data is being gathered

Comment: This is very good way to do this. I wonder why i did not come up with that, anyway thanks a million!